# codepen - why doesn't my basic reactapp run

Tags: reactjs, codepen

I am trying to setup a simple react app using codepen.  I created a very minimal, bare bones app here.

However, the app is not showing the expected output.  When the app executes successfully, the output of render method of react code is expected to replace the content of the div in the output.  But the static output doesn't change and there is no error either.

I checked up some examples of react apps in codepen, and I find my code is identical, except that I am using the latest version of react i.e. 16.4.2, as picked up by codepen, while the examples are for react 13 or react 15.  I suspect tis could be the problem, but I am unsure.

Can someone help me with a latest version of react, or point me to the error in my code?

The below is the code snippet of codepen, I recreated using stack snippet.  When I test this stack snippet, it works and give the desired output.  Stack snippet doesn't have an option to choose ReactJS 16, as the maximum version supported is 15.

Probably, it means that there is problem with reactjs 16 with codepen?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Rendering...");
    return <p> Thoooo...</p>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
html, body
  height: 100%
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  foooo
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud add references through settings.[image]]
Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmVgxm

```
    class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Rendering...");
    return <p> Thoooo...</p>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Which some exploration, I found that the default suggestion of reactjs 16.4.2 offered while searching in the settings dialog of codepen, doesn't work.

[image]

Choose a previous version of reactjs library such as (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js) by explicitly copy-pasting and the corresponding reactDOM library.

Answer (score 0):

The ReactDOM version suggested does not work with the React version suggested. I solved my issues by making the ReactDOM v16.4.2

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js